# Realm.close() giving error?

Tags: realm

I have called it as described in official documentation, in onDestroy() of my activity and initialized it in oncreate() but sometimes it gives error " Realm is already closed making it unusable"

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can share? As it stands we have no idea what you've done and can only stab in the dark as to what the problem actually is.

Comment: Sorry i cant share the code at the moment but i am facing similar problem in my service class also,i have provided the default instance in onCreate() of service and closed realm in onDestroy() ,there is no possible way realm could be closed in service class but it still gives the same error sometimes @ Guildencrantz

Comment: Are you using Java or C# - sounds from the mention of _Activity_ that you are on Android?

Comment: I assume you mean it just logs a warning? It happens if you call `close()` more times than you called `getInstance()`

Comment: No ,it crashes the app -"Unable to resume activity {com.mobile/com.mobile.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable."

Comment: And i have called close() only one time in onDestroy()

Comment: Please update your question by including code to show how you are opening and closing Realms.

Answer (score 0):

A realm object is associated with the current thread it has been obtained on. That means you can only read and write to that realm on the same thread.

> Running from a different thread? Instantiate a new realm on that
>   thread.